# map an ordered dictionary across a series

Tags: python, pandas

trying to compare a string series to an ordered dictionary and use `.lower().contains('word')` and pull back the value of the dictionary

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['Cow is good', 'pig is bad', 'Veggies are green', 'soda has sugar', 'the calf cowers']})
od = OrderedDict({'cower':'Cower',
                  'pig':'Pig',
                  'veg':'Vegetables',
                  'soda':'Soda',
                  'cow':'Cow'})
```

The importance of the ordered dictionary is because some words need to be searched first (like Cower and Cow).

I'm trying something like the below, but not sure how to get it to work.

```
df['b'] = df.a.map(lambda x: x.lower.contains(y) for y, z in od.items())
```

or

```
df.a.apply(lambda x: x.lower().map(lambda x: x.contains(y) for y, z in od.items()))
```

Expected Output:

```
                   a           b
0        Cow is good         Cow
1         pig is bad         Pig
2  Veggies are green  Vegetables
3     soda has sugar        Soda
4    the calf cowers       Cower
```

Comment: to the best of my knowledge, you need to write a loop and handle the matching there. List comprehension approaches or maps will find two matches for Cow, regardless to the ordered fashion of the dictionary. but maybe I'm wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
df['b']=  df['a'].map(lambda x: max(y if(x.lower().find(y.lower())> -1) else '' for y, z in od.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly define your comparison:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(od, columns=od.keys(), index=od.keys())
```

Hope that helps...